# QueryString into SQL selectdate= statement

Tags: javascript, sql, select, query-string, declare

Alright so I have a page that the user types in a date hits a button and a querystring is placed in my other page. I want this date that they typed to be placed into my sql statement. I am reading the querystring useing javascript at this point, but i cannot get it into my sql statement.

```
<!--
function querySt(ji) {
hu = window.location.search.substring(1);
gy = hu.split("&");
for (i=0;i<gy.length;i++) {
ft = gy[i].split("=");
if (ft[0] == ji) {
return ft[1];
}
}
}


var rundate = querySt("rundate");

document.write(rundate);
document.write("<br>");
-->
```

I was told to use a declare and set statement but i kept getting errors.. Any ideas I have been stuck on this for 2 days, im sure you all know how that feels.

```
selectdata= "SELECT............ Having dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED = CONVERT(INT, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, '11-04-2010'), 0))+2
```

Comment: using javascript? java != javascript

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do.  Typically javascript runs on the client-side (i.e. in the web browser) while SQL requests are performed on the server side (e.g. in a java servlet, a PHP page, an ASP.NET page, etc.).  There's a big piece missing in your question.

Comment: I am using ASP, not asp.net. I am trying to get the rundate(querystring) into my sql statement where the date is.

Comment: OK, but again, the javascript runs on the client side, while the VBScript in the ASP page runs on the server side.  So parsing the querystring on the client side is not going to help you.

Comment: so could you help me with a better way.

Comment: right now, they will go to a index.asp page type a date that will then be put into a rundate querystring and carried to the page called info.asp?rundate=11-02-2010. I want to somehow get this information into my sql statement

Comment: You need a much better understanding of how ASP and ADO (ASP's database access) work.  Look at the W3School tutorials (ASP: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/default.asp, ADO: http://www.w3schools.com/ado/default.asp).  Here's an example from the ADO tutorial that looks like more-or-less what you're trying to do (get a querystring from the user and incorporate it into a SQL query): http://www.w3schools.com/ado/showasp.asp?filename=demo_sort_3

Comment: THANK YOU I MEANT TO GIVE YOU THE ANSWER!!

Comment: Eh, given that your original question was actually fairly far off from what you needed to ask (i.e. the real answer doesn't have to do with javascript) it makes more sense to keep it all in the comments.  I have lots of rep points.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try breaking the problem down into parts.  Ignore the sql stuff for now, just make sure your function is getting the string correctly and breaking out the "rundate" parameter.  That part looks ok, as long as the line
 window.location.search;
is  actually getting a correct string.

Two suggestions that probably don't apply to your problem, but are good practice: use alert() rather than document.write(), and put "var" before local variables so they don't pollute global namespace.  That is:

```
var gy = hu.split("&");
```

etc.

Comment: yeah the function is getting the correct information, thats why i had it write it to the page. the next step is to somehow get this information into my sql statement : ( and i have been searching everywhere